# Drools 7.2 KieServices NullPointerException

Tags: drools, kie, jboss-tools

I have successfully been using Drools with Apache Spark for quite a while now. When I performed an upgraded from 7.1 to 7.2 I started encountering a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This occurs when I attempt to instantiate an instance of the KieServices class:

```
val service = KieServices.Factory.get()
```

I did a [comparison](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge/compare/7.1.x...7.2.x) between 7.1.x and 7.2.x

It looks like the the process for instantiating the instance of the KieServices class has completely changed. Does anyone know why this would have stopped working in a Spark cluster? Is this potentially a bug with Drools? I am not sure what other information I can give since it was working properly before the change.

**Notes:**

1. I also tested this on version 7.3.Final and 7.4.Final with the same results.

Comment: You may need to go straight to Drools' IRC channel and ask there whether this is a "feature" or a bug.

Comment: I tried using the IRC channel, but didn't get a response. I posted in the google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/Rm6q3lJ468E